# Module that follows as page scrolls PHP

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a Module that follows as page scrolls in PHP. I know that's not really that good at describing it, Let me try to do it a little better. So I need to have a box about 500X50 at the bottom of the user's page. As the user scrolls up or down the box is still at the bottom of the page. It moves with the page scrolls per say. I can't think of a way to do this. I only know PHP and HTML so I'd rather not have to work with js or jquery for this. If at all possible I'd love it to be able to be done in iframe, But from the documents I read about iframe it can't be done with iframe alone.

If you'd like to know why. I'm coding this for a MyBB forum, this box will display active forum info.

Comment: You can do this with css. PHP is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate tool for this is CSS, specifically `position:fixed`.  Something like this:

```
#your-box {
     width:500px;
     height:50px;
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0;
}
```

In general, CSS is better than either PHP or HTML for defining *how* content should appear (as opposed to defining *what* content should appear).  That's what it's there for.  You can read more about CSS positioning at [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to describe is `position:fixed`. I've put a [sample here on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64Wn9/), core CSS for styling the floating box and centering it horizontally on the bottom:

```
#floater {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    height:1.5em;
    width:400px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    background:navy;
    border:1px solid blue;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

For completion's sake - the fact that I used a `div` is moot here. Make an iframe with id `floater` and it'll work the same, or put an iframe inside the div.